# C# google geolocation Api's administrative_area_level_2 value from JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps, google-api

From C#, `JsonConvert` I am looking to get google geolocation api values of `administrative_area_level_2` --> `long_name`

```
 http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=T1X%200L3&sensor=true
```

What I am trying is :-

```
dynamic part = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseJson);
    string name = part.results.address_components.types.administrative_area_level_2;
```

what should be the correct way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste your JSON to [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) and create all suggested classes in your project. Then we can deserialize the json string into `RootObject` and access any part of the JSON easily from strongly typed object, for example :

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseJson);
var address_type = "administrative_area_level_2";
string name = root.results[0]
                  .address_components
                  .FirstOrDefault(o => o.types.Contains(address_type))
                  .long_name;
```

You can also accomplish this without creating new classes like so :

```
var root = JObject.Parse(responseJson);
var address_type = "administrative_area_level_2";
string name = root["results"][0]
                  ["address_components"]
                  .FirstOrDefault(a => (a["types"]).Select(t => (string)t)
                                                   .Contains(address_type))
                  ["long_name"];
```

Comment: string name = 'obj' what would be the obj here

Comment: @user3226440 Does any one (or both) of suggested approaches above worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

if you want JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to work you will need to have the same structured object and `DeserializeObject<newObjectName>` with it.

the result object doesn't seem to be to complex:
the lists of objects can be either Arrays or ILists.

you can use :http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ to parse the result in a more viewable state.

If you want the way you are accessing( much less elegant way) you can try:

```
part["result"]["..."][0]
```